# sklearn grid search with grouped K fold cv generator

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cross-validation

I am trying to implement a grid search over parameters in sklearn using randomized search and a grouped k fold cross-validation generator.  The following works:

```
skf=StratifiedKFold(n_splits=5,shuffle=True,random_state=0)
rs=sklearn.model_selection.RandomizedSearchCV(clf,parameters,scoring='roc_auc',cv=skf,n_iter=10)
rs.fit(X,y)
```

This doesn't

```
gkf=GroupKFold(n_splits=5)
rs=sklearn.model_selection.RandomizedSearchCV(clf,parameters,scoring='roc_auc',cv=gkf,n_iter=10)
rs.fit(X,y)

#ValueError: The groups parameter should not be None
```

How do I indicate the `groups` parameter?

Neither does this

```
gkf=GroupKFold(n_splits=5)
fv = gkf.split(X, y, groups=groups)
rs=sklearn.model_selection.RandomizedSearchCV(clf,parameters,scoring='roc_auc',cv=gkf,n_iter=10)
rs.fit(X,y)

#TypeError: object of type 'generator' has no len()
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

For reference, this is done via

```
rs.fit(X,y,groups=groups)
```

for

```
rs=sklearn.model_selection.RandomizedSearchCV(forest,parameters,scoring='roc_auc',cv=gkf,n_iter=10)
```